# How significant is the material in drag force calculations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics

I went to Wolfram's "Drag Force Calculator" and received 4900 newtons for a cone that has a radius of 3 meters and a height of 3 meters, moving through air at a standard pressure, 15 celsius, at a speed of 20 m/s.

I looked up the cone drag coefficient and it was 0.50, and it does not appear that any further information is required. The material does make a difference, of course, but is the difference so miniscule that it's not worth adding?

Comment: Typically the drag coefficient only depends on the geometry of the object, not the material it is made of.

Comment: The drag coefficient is probably independent of the material of the cane but the surface is probably assumed to be "smooth" . If it was "rough" the drag coefficient would change.

Comment: @Farcher and that it is rigid. Computing drag when the profile changes with the drag force is a real pain !

Comment: The "material" would give the density of the cone and hence it's mass. The mass and velocity give the cone momentum which opposes the drag.

Comment: Why do you expect the material (of the cone) to make a difference to the drag force?

Comment: Indeed, material has no effect on drag force, unless it changes geometry of object somehow. For example if you take some very porous material,- it will let part of air "through", effectively changing frontal effective area. So $1m^2$ of metal plate and $1m^2$ of porous material is not the same. But other than that, all other things being equal, drag does not depend directly on material which object is made of.

Answer (score -1):

As the material of which something is made of affects an object's mass, given two objects with different densities but with exactly the same surfaces (size, shape, texture), the more dense object will be subject to less drag deceleration. Surface shape and texture are important factors as well. This is, for example, why dimples on golf balls are highly regulated, why baseballs scuff with dirt are highly prized by pitchers (and tossed by umpires), and why airplane engineers are constantly toying with slight changes to the shape of a wing.

An exception to the above occurs above the Karman line. Shape and texture don't matter nearly as much in the very thin air of the upper atmosphere. Just about everything has a coefficient of drag of 2.2 (or higher) in the thermosphere.

Comment: The question was about the drag force, not the resulting deceleration. The mass of an object has no effect on its aerodynamic drag force.